# Overriding JS function

Tags: javascript

this is an original function from Framework I'm working with. It's a Python-based framework with a little bit Javascript. and as I do not really know much about JS I want to ask a question.

How can I override `init: function (parent, options)` part.

in that function, I need to change just one thing. 
line 57

[link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/mail/static/src/js/thread.js)

`display_order: ORDER.ASC` to `ORDER.DESC`

so i need somehow to call this functions in super and change arguments

```
var Thread = Widget.extend({
    className: 'o_mail_thread',

    events: {
        "click a": "on_click_redirect",
        "click img": "on_click_redirect",
        "click strong": "on_click_redirect",
        "click .o_thread_show_more": "on_click_show_more",
        "click .o_thread_message_needaction": function (event) {
            var message_id = $(event.currentTarget).data('message-id');
            this.trigger("mark_as_read", message_id);
        },
        "click .o_thread_message_star": function (event) {
            var message_id = $(event.currentTarget).data('message-id');
            this.trigger("toggle_star_status", message_id);
        },
        "click .o_thread_message_reply": function (event) {
            this.selected_id = $(event.currentTarget).data('message-id');
            this.$('.o_thread_message').removeClass('o_thread_selected_message');
            this.$('.o_thread_message[data-message-id=' + this.selected_id + ']')
                .addClass('o_thread_selected_message');
            this.trigger('select_message', this.selected_id);
            event.stopPropagation();
        },
        "click .oe_mail_expand": function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $message = $(event.currentTarget).parents('.o_thread_message');
            $message.addClass('o_message_expanded');
            this.expanded_msg_ids.push($message.data('message-id'));
        },
        "click .o_thread_message": function (event) {
            $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('o_thread_selected_message');
        },
        "click": function () {
            if (this.selected_id) {
                this.unselect();
                this.trigger('unselect_message');
            }
        },
    },

    init: function (parent, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.options = _.defaults(options || {}, {
            display_order: ORDER.ASC,
            display_needactions: true,
            display_stars: true,
            display_document_link: true,
            display_avatar: true,
            shorten_messages: true,
            squash_close_messages: true,
            display_reply_icon: false,
        });
        this.expanded_msg_ids = [];
        this.selected_id = null;
    },
```

Comment: It looks like `init()` takes an `options` argument. You should be able to pass in that option rather than overriding the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're unable or not interested in changing the source code, you can pass 
`{display_order: ORDER.DESC}` as the options parameter when creating this class.